# PHP Illegal String

Tags: php

```
$d = $_SESSION['post'];
    unset($_SESSION['post']);
    foreach($d as $k => $v) {
        \sys\CDatabase::query('UPDATE sportart SET
            name = "?name",
            reihenfolge = "?reihenfolge"
        WHERE sportart_id = "?id"',array(
            'name'=>$v['name'],
            'reihenfolge'=>$v['reihenfolge'],
            'id'=>$k
        ),'none');
    }
```

need fast help on this code pls, every time i try it an error occurs which says

```
Illegal string offset 'name'
```

Comment: What is the output of var_dump($d)?

Comment: array(3) { [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(4) "Schi" ["reihenfolge"]=> string(1) "1" } [2]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(9) "Snowboard" ["reihenfolge"]=> string(1) "2" } ["model"]=> string(31) "models\BackendSportartenAendern" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array `$d` contains values of mixed types. One of the values is a string (a kind of model name, according to your comment: `"model" => "models\BackendSportartenAendern"`).

Thus the error: you're trying to use the string as if it were a (sub-)array.

One easy way to fix the code is to modify your loop so that non-array values are skipped:

```
foreach($d as $k => $v) {
    if (!is_array($v)) {
        continue;
    }

    \sys\CDatabase::query(...);
}
```